# Concatenate Picklists In Formula

Tags: apex, formula

I am creating a formula field to concatenate the picklist value with nested if..How can i achieve this as my formula is not working

my requirement  is

```
IF Pricing Method=[A, B, Firm]…Cost Method='A' 
if...Pricing Method=T&M ]…Cost Method='Cost and T&M'
if...Pricing Method=[T&M ]…Cost Method='Cost and T&M'
```

I wrote below formula

```
IF (ISPICKVAL(Pricing__c , "Cost Only") || ISPICKVAL( Pricing__c , "Budgetary") || ISPICKVAL( Pricing__c , "Firm"),"Cost Only","" ) AND( IF(Account_Country__c = "T&M Price List","Cost '+' T&M Price List", IF(Account_Country__c = "T&M Discounted","Cost '+' T&M Discounted",)))
```

Comment: I wrote below formulaIF (ISPICKVAL(Pricing__c , "Cost Only") || ISPICKVAL( Pricing__c   , "Budgetary") || 
ISPICKVAL( Pricing__c   , "Firm"),"Cost Only","" )

AND(
IF(Account_Country__c = "T&M Price List","Cost '+' T&M Price List",
IF(Account_Country__c = "T&M Discounted","Cost '+' T&M Discounted",)))

Comment: you can use `{}` for formatting code

Comment: I have corrected the formula and it works now.Thank you guys                       
IF ( 
ISPICKVAL(Pricing__c , "Cost Only") || 
ISPICKVAL( Pricing__c , "Budgetary") || 
ISPICKVAL( Pricing__c , "Firm"), 
"Cost Only", 
IF ( 
ISPICKVAL(Pricing__c , "T&M Price List"), 
"Cost and T&M Price List", 
IF( 
ISPICKVAL(Pricing__c , "T&M Discounted"), 
"Cost and T&M Discounted","" 
) 
) 
)

Comment: Do you get an error? Please **[edit]** your post to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missing commas where you need them, and extras where they don't belong. You have also confused yourself by mixing `||` and `AND`; their syntax is different. I recommend you stick to `AND` and `OR` for a few reasons, syntactic consistency among them. However I will first show you with `&&` and `||` as I think you may find it less confusing.

```
IF (
    ISPICKVAL(Pricing__c , "Cost Only") ||
    ISPICKVAL( Pricing__c , "Budgetary") ||
    ISPICKVAL( Pricing__c , "Firm"),"Cost Only","" ) // here you incorrectly mixed syntax
    AND(
        IF(
            Account_Country__c = "T&M Price List",
            "Cost '+' T&M Price List",
            IF(
                Account_Country__c = "T&M Discounted",
                "Cost '+' T&M Discounted",
                // Missing fallback argument
            )
        )
    )
    // Missing comma, fallback, and close paren for outer if
```

Please note the syntax:

- `IF(condition, value_if_true, value_if_false)`
- `AND(condition1, condition2, condition3, etc)`
- `OR(condition1, condition2, condition3, etc)`

Another note, it is much more efficient to use `CASE` to evaluate many picklist options. Here is what you were probably going for:

```
IF (
    0 < CASE(
        Pricing__c,
        "Cost Only", 1,
        "Budgetary", 1,
        "Firm", 1,
        0
    ),
    "Cost Only",
    CASE(
        Account_Country__c,
        "T&M Price List", "Cost '+' T&M Price List",
        "T&M Discounted", "Cost '+' T&M Discounted",
        "Put some fallback value here"
    )
)
```

Comment: Adding more content...